# Is there a transatlantic split in how to truncate "obstetrics and gynecology"?

Tags: american-english, british-english, medical

There is a medical specialty called obstetrics and gynecology.  In the UK I have only heard this truncated to something like the first syllables separated by a truncated "and".  This could perhaps be written as "obs 'n gy-nee".

I have multiple times recently heard this specialty referred to by Americans by spelling out prominent early letters, an initialism.  This could perhaps be written as "oh bee gee why en" (as in one spelling out OB GYN).

Is this a UK/US difference?  Is there a "right" way to abbreviate this specialty?  I am particularly interested in how it is said, as opposed to how it is written.

Comment: My mother is a medical doctor specializing in genetics and deals frequently with OBGYN's. I have never heard her (or anyone else) shorten it to anything except OBGYN with each letter pronounced individually, as you say. (This is AmE.)

Comment: In BE is shortened to O&G (Oh and gee) -- *"Doctors in obstetrics and gynaecology (O&G) care for pregnant women and unborn children, and look after women’s sexual and reproductive health."*  https://www.healthcareers.nhs.uk/explore-roles/doctors/roles-doctors/obstetrics-and-gynaecology/obstetrics-and-gynaecology

Comment: Truncation is an unfortunate word to use for this question.

Comment: @Lambie If you have a better suggestion feel free to make it

Answer (score 8):

**American English** 
OB-GYN is a common informal way to express the medical specialty of Obstetrics and Gynecology in speech. It is pronounced letter by letter, as **oh-bee-gee-why-enn**, not as an acronym. See the [Cambridge Advanced Learner's Dictionary of American English](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/ob-gyn):

> ob-gyn US informal (also OB/GYN, ob/gyn) is the abbreviation for obstetrician-gynecologist

According to the Cambridge Academic Content Dictionary (Intermediate English)

> OB-GYN US medical is the abbreviation for obstetrics and gynecology

Exceptions would be formal usage, e.g. journal articles, or medical specialty directories. In those contexts, it would be spelled out completely. An ampersand is not used between obstetrics and gynecology. Canadian and American English have the same usage, even though Canada is a Commonwealth Nation.

**British English** 
According to [Wiktionary, in British English](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/obs_and_gynae), the term is

> obs and gynae
> alternative form O&G

I cannot find a good reference for it, but in British English, Obs and Gynae is pronounced obs 'n' guy-knee.

The [UK NHS abbreviates it as O&G](https://www.healthcareers.nhs.uk/explore-roles/doctors/roles-doctors/obstetrics-and-gynaecology/obstetrics-and-gynaecology). The [Royal College of Obstetrics and Gynaecology ("For the Public")](https://www.rcog.org.uk/for-the-public/) doesn't provide any guidance about abbreviations or pronunciation.

Note this too: In the United States, some medical practitioners only provide  gynecological care, i.e. they do not provide care for pregnant women and delivering infants. They are trained to do obstetrics, but for various reasons (one of which is liability insurance costs) they choose to focus solely on gynecology. In that case, a medical provider would be referred to as a gynecologist not as a "gyn" or any other abbreviation.

Comment: (Midwest) Americans also say *gynae* but not *obs*. I've never heard the word *obstetrics*, only *an obstetrician* or *my OB-GYN* or *a gynae*.

Comment: Thanks, @Mazura for mentioning that about midwest American English also saying *gynae*. I've heard it pronounced *gyno* with a long o in the U.S., but don't recall where. "Obstetrics" is the field of study for obstetricians; OB or obstetrician is just a way of saying that the caregiver is a provider of obstetric type medical care.

Answer (score 2):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obstetrics_and_gynaecology) [reformatted} licenses various abbreviations:

> Obstetrics and Gynaecology (also spelled as Obstetrics and Gynecology;
> abbreviated as
>
> - Obs and Gynae
> - O&G
> - OB-GYN
>
> and
>
> - OB/GYN
>
> is the medical specialty that encompasses ....

[Acronym Finder](https://www.acronymfinder.com/Obstetrics-and-Gynecology-(OBGYN).html) adds the 'clean' initialism

- OBGYN

with the rider 'This definition appears very frequently'.

All the spelling variants of OBGYN would be pronounced similarly if not identically.

As for O&G: it is second level on the Likert-like scale [Acronym Finder](https://www.acronymfinder.com/O-%26-G.html) provide, out-competed by the expansions 'oil and gas' and 'organization and governance'. These sound like US-based usages, perhaps bolstering the suspicion that OBGYN (which I've never come across in the UK) is the favoured variant in the States. But O&G is the abbreviation the [NHS](https://www.healthcareers.nhs.uk/explore-roles/doctors/roles-doctors/obstetrics-and-gynaecology/obstetrics-and-gynaecology) (UK) use.